# strict.pm did not return a true value at (eval 1) line 2

Tags: perl, debian, dpkg

I have a VPS with the following System installed:

```
CPU model            : Common KVM processor
Number of cores      : 1
CPU frequency        : 2499.998 MHz
Total size of Disk   : 30.0 GB (6.0 GB Used)
Total amount of Mem  : 1995 MB (1043 MB Used)
Total amount of Swap : 0 MB (0 MB Used)
OS                   : Debian GNU/Linux 10
Arch                 : x86_64 (64 Bit)
Kernel               : 4.19.0-8-amd64
```

with only Mailcow (dockerized) installed. I then wanted to install some packages like sudo and for some reason the following error pops up:

```
root@mx:~#  aptitude upgrade
The following packages will be upgraded:
  docker-ce docker-ce-cli
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  debconf
The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
  aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount libltdl7 pigz
2 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/65.4 MB of archives. After unpacking 19.5 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (strict.pm did not return a true value at (eval 1) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 2.
) -- aborting
Setting up debconf (1.5.71) ...
strict.pm did not return a true value at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 5.
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 installed debconf package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Specifically this error catched my attention:

```
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (strict.pm did not return a true value at (eval 1) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 2.
) -- aborting
```

I've been trying to fix this issue with no success at all.

Try #1:
perl -e 'use strict' returns this:

```
strict.pm did not return a true value at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
```

Try #2:
cd /var/cache/apt/archives, then dpkg -i perl_5.28.1-6_amd64.deb and dpkg -i perl-base_5.28.1-6_amd64.deb results in this:

```
root@mx:~# cd /var/cache/apt/archives
root@mx:/var/cache/apt/archives# dpkg -i perl-base_5.28.1-6_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 40477 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack perl-base_5.28.1-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking perl-base (5.28.1-6) over (5.28.1-6) ...
Setting up perl-base (5.28.1-6) ...
root@mx:/var/cache/apt/archives# dpkg -i perl_5.28.1-6_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package perl.
(Reading database ... 40477 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack perl_5.28.1-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking perl (5.28.1-6) over (5.28.1-6) ...
Setting up perl (5.28.1-6) ...
root@mx:/var/cache/apt/archives#
```

Try #3:

```
apt reinstall perl results in this:
root@mx:/var/cache/apt/archives# apt reinstall perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/204 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (strict.pm did not return a true value at (eval 1) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 2.
) -- aborting
Setting up debconf (1.5.71) ...
strict.pm did not return a true value at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 5.
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 installed debconf package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@mx:/var/cache/apt/archives#
```

Try #4:
Since perl5 isn't installed, I tried purging perl and reinstalling it with apt remove --purge perl && sudo apt install perl
Results are:

```
root@mx:/var/cache/apt/archives# apt remove --purge perl && sudo apt install perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  git-man libapt-pkg-perl libcurl3-gnutls libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libperl5.28 patch perl-modules-5.28
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt-file* git* libcgi-fast-perl* libcgi-pm-perl* libclass-accessor-perl* libencode-locale-perl* liberror-perl* libexporter-tiny-perl* libfcgi-perl* libhtml-parser-perl* libhtml-tagset-perl*
  libhttp-date-perl* libhttp-message-perl* libio-html-perl* libio-string-perl* liblist-moreutils-perl* liblwp-mediatypes-perl* libparse-debianchangelog-perl* libregexp-assemble-perl* libsub-name-perl*
  libtimedate-perl* liburi-perl* perl*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 23 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 39.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (strict.pm did not return a true value at (eval 1) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 2.
) -- aborting
Setting up debconf (1.5.71) ...
strict.pm did not return a true value at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 5.
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 installed debconf package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@mx:/var/cache/apt/archives#
```

Try #5:
perl -V returns this:

```
root@mx:/usr/share/perl/5.28.1# perl -V
strict.pm did not return a true value at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28/Config.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28/Config.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

About strict.pm, it seems to be localted in /usr/share/perl/5.28.1/strict.pm and contains a massive long line with the following:

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^ (and so on ..)
```

"fixed" it by simply replacing it with

```
1;
__END__
```

but now the following error occours:

```
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (IO/File.pm did not return a true value at /usr/share/perl/5.28/FileHandle.pm line 9.
```

and that file, IO/File.pm, seems to not exist - adding it manually didn't help.

Try #6:
With the help of @ikegami (comments), strict.pm has been fixed, yet the following files seem broken still (specifically IO/File.pm):

```
Setting up debconf (1.5.71) ...
IO/File.pm did not return a true value at /usr/share/perl/5.28/FileHandle.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Template.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Template.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Log.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 7.
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 installed debconf package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Info #1:
root@mx:/usr/share/perl/5.28# find /usr/share/perl -name '*.pm' -exec perl

```
-0777ne'print "$ARGV\n" if /\0/' {} +
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Net/FTP/A.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Net/FTP/I.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Net/FTP/L.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Net/FTP/E.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Net/FTP/dataconn.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Net/FTP.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Net/SMTP.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Net/hostent.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Net/Time.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/utf8.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Pod/Html.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Pod/Functions.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Pod/Find.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/sigtrap.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/perlfaq.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/subs.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Socket/IP.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Compress/Zlib/Constants.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Compress/Zlib/Extra.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Compress/Gzip/Constants.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Compress/Gzip.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Compress/RawDeflate.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Uncompress/RawInflate.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Uncompress/Adapter/Identity.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Uncompress/Adapter/Bunzip2.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Uncompress/Base.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Uncompress/Unzip.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Uncompress/Bunzip2.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/vmsish.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Locale/Codes/LangFam_Codes.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Locale/Codes/LangVar.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Locale/Codes/LangExt_Retired.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Locale/Codes/LangFam_Retired.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Locale/Codes/LangFam.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Test2/API/Stack.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Test2/Event.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Test2/API.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Test2/Event/Waiting.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Test2/EventFacet/Info.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Test2/EventFacet/Amnesty.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Test2/EventFacet/About.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Test2/EventFacet/Assert.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Test2/EventFacet/Hub.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Test2/EventFacet/Control.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Test2/EventFacet/Error.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/overload/numbers.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/sort.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/parent.pm
```

Info #2:
root@mx: find / -name "File.pm"

```
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Archive/Tar/File.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/TAP/Parser/SourceHandler/File.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/TAP/Formatter/File.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/Tie/File.pm
/usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28.1/IO/File.pm
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base/IO/File.pm
```

Comment: edited, error still appears.

Comment: same error, is there any other way to reinstall perl or am I missing some other packages that have to be reinstalled?

Comment: Tried that as well, updated question.

Comment: What does `perl --version` give?

Comment: The following: This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

Comment: `perl -V` (uppercase `v`) will report, among other things, the paths in `@INC`. Could you find the first one of those paths that contain `strict.pm`, report that path to us, and provide the contents of that file? (Should have a line containing `1;` followed by a line containing `__END__`.)

Comment: The file is garbage. Try replacing it with [this](https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/SHAY/perl-5.28.1/lib/strict.pm)

Comment: question updated, I also removed ^@^@^@ with 1; and __END__ - the error is gone but now another file does almost the same thing

Comment: (`^@` represents byte `00`)

Comment: You could try to identify the corrupt files using `find /usr/share/perl -name '*.pm' -exec perl -0777ne'print "$ARGV\n" if /\0/' {} +`. We can fix those are needed by `debconf` so that you can reinstall `perl` using `apt` to fix the remainder

Comment: (You need to tag comments with `@ikegami` if you want me to be notified. It was luck that I noticed your update.)

Comment: The above command won't catch corrupted binary files (.so), but I'm hoping that `debconf` doesn't use any modules with a binary component.

Comment: The alternative solution is to install Perl manually. That's actually pretty easy, but replacing package manager-controller `perl` with a manually installed one could cause problems in the future

Comment: @ikegami fixed the strict.pm file, thanks. Updated question with what to seem to be broken.

Comment: The line 9 (mentioned in as error IO/File.pm did not return a true value at /usr/share/perl/5.28/FileHandle.pm line 9) has following content: require IO::File;

Comment: I'm not keen on doing it one file at at time. What about the `find` command I mentioned?

Comment: [`IO/File.pm`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/dist/IO/lib/IO/File.pm) from 5.28.1

Comment: @ikegami added it, interestingly, Info #2 perl-base's files seem valid, I may copy paste it over to perl/5.28.1 (?)

Comment: Your linux distro splits Perl into two distros (`perl` and `perl-base`). I don't know why `IO/File.pm` would be in both. But let's not start doing wild changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issuing the following commands should fix enough corrupted files to allow you to reinstall Perl using `apt`:

```sh
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/utf8.pm                             curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/lib/utf8.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/subs.pm                             curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/lib/subs.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Socket/IP.pm                     curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/cpan/IO-Socket-IP/lib/IO/Socket/IP.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Compress/Zlib/Constants.pm       curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/cpan/IO-Compress/lib/IO/Compress/Zlib/Constants.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Compress/Zlib/Extra.pm           curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/cpan/IO-Compress/lib/IO/Compress/Zlib/Extra.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Compress/Gzip/Constants.pm       curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/cpan/IO-Compress/lib/IO/Compress/Gzip/Constants.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Compress/Gzip.pm                 curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/cpan/IO-Compress/lib/IO/Compress/Gzip.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Compress/RawDeflate.pm           curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/cpan/IO-Compress/lib/IO/Compress/RawDeflate.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Uncompress/RawInflate.pm         curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/cpan/IO-Compress/lib/IO/Uncompress/RawInflate.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Uncompress/Adapter/Identity.pm   curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/cpan/IO-Compress/lib/IO/Uncompress/Adapter/Identity.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Uncompress/Adapter/Bunzip2.pm    curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/cpan/IO-Compress/lib/IO/Uncompress/Adapter/Bunzip2.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Uncompress/Base.pm               curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/cpan/IO-Compress/lib/IO/Uncompress/Base.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Uncompress/Unzip.pm              curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/cpan/IO-Compress/lib/IO/Uncompress/Unzip.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Uncompress/Bunzip2.pm            curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/cpan/IO-Compress/lib/IO/Uncompress/Bunzip2.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/overload/numbers.pm                 curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/lib/overload/numbers.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/sort.pm                             curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/lib/sort.pm
>/usr/share/perl/5.28.1/parent.pm                           curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/v5.28.1/cpan/parent/lib/parent.pm
```